# I'm trying to create a SQL query using an inner join but I'm getting a syntax error for my first inner join statement

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT 
    u.userId, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.emailAddress, 
    u.phoneNumber, ap.date, ap.time, a.balance 
FROM 
    users u 
WHERE 
    u.firstName = 'first_name' 
    AND u.lastName = 'last_name' 
    AND u.emailAddress = 'email@gmail.com' 
INNER JOIN 
    accounts a ON u.userId =  a.userId 
INNER JOIN 
    appointments ap ON u.userId = ap.userId;
```

Comment: That's because you're using the `JOIN` statements after the `WHERE` clause. They come before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query syntax sequence is wrong. If you want to JOIN any table it should come after your parent table.

```
SELECT u.userId, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.emailAddress, u.phoneNumber, ap.date, ap.time, a.balance 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN accounts a ON u.userId = a.userId 
INNER JOIN appointments ap ON u.userId = ap.userId
WHERE u.firstName = 'first_name' AND u.lastName = 'last_name' AND u.emailAddress = 'email@gmail.com';
```

Check on https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your `JOIN` statements go before the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    u.userId,
    u.firstName,
    u.lastName,
    u.emailAddress,
    u.phoneNumber,
    ap.date,
    ap.time,
    a.balance 
FROM
    users u  
    INNER JOIN accounts a ON u.userId =  a.userId 
    INNER JOIN appointments ap ON u.userId = ap.userId
WHERE
    u.firstName = 'first_name'
    AND u.lastName = 'last_name'
    AND u.emailAddress = 'email@gmail.com';
```